# Flutter - How to verify InAppPurchases (iOS)

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I've tried to implement in-app purchases of non-consumable items but I got stuck with the verification of the purchase, atleast on iOS.
Whenever I make the function "_verifyPurchase()" just return true, everything is fine.
That's what makes me think that the verifying process is the problem.

```dart
  Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(String productID) async {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
    PurchaseDetails purchase = await _hasPurchased(productID);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print('verify'+purchase?.productID.toString()+(purchase?.error).toString());
    if (purchase != null &&
        (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || purchase.transactionDate != null) &&
        _kProductIds.contains(productID)) {
      if(productID == _kProductIds[0]) {
        print('has purchased remove ads');
        prefs.setBool(productID, true);
        setState(() {
          appState.setBoughtRemoveAds = true;
        });
      }else if(productID == _kProductIds[1]){
        print('has purchased premium');
        prefs.setBool(productID, true);
        setState(() {
          appState.setBoughtPremium = true;
        });
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I don't want to verify the purchase server-sided and think the "_hasPurchased()" function is most likely broken

```dart
Future<PurchaseDetails> _hasPurchased(String productID) async {
    final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.queryPastPurchases();
    return response.pastPurchases.firstWhere((purchase) => purchase.productID == productID,
        orElse: () => null);
  }
```

I've followed the tutorial by [Fireship.io](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWbkKH-2xcQ)

Edit: minor mistake in code.

Answer (score 12):

After spending hours finally I was able to solve this issue, unfortunately both plugins ([in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) and [flutter_inapp_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase)) for flutter does not share this information very clearly how you can verify your purchase recipt, here is the example code.

solution 1: Make a post request from the app (Not Recommended)

```
     Future<http.Response> validateReceiptIos(receiptBody,isTest) async {
          final String url = isTest
            ? 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt'
             : 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
           return  await http.post(
           Uri.parse(url),
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
            body: json.encode(receiptBody),
              );
             }
```

Pass the function arguments

```
    var receiptBody = {
    'receipt-data': purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData, // receipt key you will receive in request purchase callback function 
    'exclude-old-transactions':true,
     'password':'You can get this from App store-> In app purchase-> App specific shared secert'
     };
```

Solution 2: (Recommended Solution)
On your API server make an API and call the [sandbox] or for [production] [3](https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt)
this and then later use this api in your app.

Comment: How did you handle this for google play store?

Comment: @bky its been over a year now I dont have access to project anymore, please check the respective plugins documentation.

Comment: Just mentioning that in 2023 verifyReceipt is deprecated (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store), but not sure there is anything else for the flutter in_app_purchase flow

Comment: Also, shared secret is now under App Store -> App Information -> App-Specific Shared Secret

Answer (score 3):

While I love fireship.io. This tutorial is lacking in that he doesn't teach you how to properly verify the purchase.

I also followed the tutorial but found it wanting in regards to verification. I am focused on Android doing a subscription and I came across these docs https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Verify which were kind of difficult to understand since I wanted to try to verify on the device.

I switched to RevenueCat https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter and they handle the verification on the server side for you and I've found it to be much easier.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. More information about how to write a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the `return true` line inside the nested if statements because the function will verify that a user has purchased all of the products even though he/she may have just purchased one. Also, the conditions inside your nested if statements are the same, both `productID == _kProductIds[0]`

```
 if (purchase != null &&
        (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || purchase.transactionDate != null) &&
        _kProductIds.contains(productID)) {
      if(productID == _kProductIds[0]) {
        print('has purchased remove ads');
        prefs.setBool(productID, true);
        setState(() {
          appState.setBoughtRemoveAds = true;
        });
        return true;
      }else if(productID == _kProductIds[0]){
        print('has purchased premium');
        prefs.setBool(productID, true);
        setState(() {
          appState.setBoughtRemoveAds = true;
        });
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I corrected the code, however it sadly still did not work.

Answer (score -2):

I got has the function "_hasPurchased" to work if I check the purchase ids against each other. The checking whole object again each other fails. One could run more comparisons than just ids.

So I added this :

```
bool _comparePurchaseDetails(PurchaseDetails pd0, PurchaseDetails pd1){
if(pd0.purchaseID != pd1.purchaseID)return false;
if(pd0.verificationData.serverVerificationData != pd1.verificationData.serverVerificationData)return false;
if(pd0.verificationData.localVerificationData != pd1.verificationData.localVerificationData)return false;
return true;
```

}